# Segmentation Fault with delete even using virtual destructor

Tags: c++

I am getting segmentation fault while deleting an objected, being referenced by the pointer of the base class, even when I have declared the destructor virtual!

here is my Code

```
class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual ~Shape()
        {
            cout<<"Shape destructor is called!"<<endl;      
        }

};    

class Line : public Shape
{
    public:
    ~Line()
        {
        cout<<"Line destructor is called!"<<endl;       
    }

};

int main()
{
Line myLine;
Shape* myShapePtr  = &myLine; //Line A

delete myShapePtr;
}
```

`

### Output

Line destructor is called!

Shape destructor is called!

./runCP.sh: line 2:  2915 Segmentation fault      ./a.out

I understand that in Line A, the object is getting sliced, and this is the reason,I am getting this error. But, yet I cant figure out how object slicing could cause segmentation fault.

If the object has been sliced, then virtual destructor must not have been called, but here virtual destructor is also called.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Slicing doesn’t mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only `delete` an object allocated with `new`.

`myShapePtr` does not point to an object allocated with `new`, it points to `myLine`, which is a local variable.

As a local variable, `myLine` has automatic storage duration.  It will be destroyed *automatically* when the `}` that ends the block in which it is declared is reached.

Answer (score 5):

You are only allowed to use `delete` on objects created with `new`, using `delete` on anything else, local variables included, is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

you can't delete an object which is on the stack. you have to instantiate it with `new` first:

```
Shape* MyShapePtr = new Line();
delete MyShapePtr;
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared `myLine` on the stack. In C++ it will *automatically* get destructed when it goes out of scope (`}`) so deleting it is incorrect code.

You should only (and always) use `delete` on memory returned from `new`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have faced this as an interview question, appease the interviewer by overloading `delete operator`!